# How to pass variables into functions?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to not have any global variables and I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass the database var into the addTrain function. Do I need to have global variables for the database?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function mainProgram(){
    var config = {};        // Initialize Firebase
    var database;           // Variable to reference the database

    config = {
    apiKey: "#",
    authDomain: "#",
    databaseURL: "#",
    projectId: "#",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "#"
  };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    database = firebase.database();

    $("#train-submit").click(addTrain);
}

//calls the main function
mainProgram()


// add train function
function addTrain(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");

    var name;           // Train name
    var destination;    // Train destination
    var arrivalTime;    // inputted arrival time
    var frequency;      // How often train arrives
    var timeStamp;      // FB timestamp

    var formatTime;     // Format for moment.js
    var convertedTime;  // converted time
    var displayTime;    // converted time for displaying in DOM
    var timeLeft;       // time left until next train


    name = $("#train-name").val().trim();
    destination = $("#train-destination").val().trim();
    arrivalTime = $("#train-time").val().trim();
    frequency = $("#train-frequency").val().trim();
    formatTime = "HH mm";
    convertedTime = moment(arrivalTime, formatTime);
    displayTime = moment(convertedTime).format("HH:mm")
    timeLeft = moment(convertedTime).fromNow();


    database.ref("/train-data").set({
        name: name,
        destination: destination,
        frequency: frequency,
        arrivalTime: arrivalTime,
        timeStamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    })

    console.log("input captured: " + name);
    console.log("input captured: " + destination);
    console.log("input captured: " + frequency);
    console.log("input captured: " + arrivalTime);
    console.log("converted convertedTime: " + convertedTime);
    console.log("converted displayTime: " + displayTime);
    console.log("converted timeLeft: " + timeLeft);

 }  
});
```

Do I pass in database in the mainProgram() call? Like mainProgram(database)? Something like that? I think I've set this up all wrong. I'm in a coding bootcamp and I'm really struggling on wrapping my head around passing in varialbes and scope. Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code that calls `addTrain()`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus `$("#train-submit").click(addTrain);`

Comment: Change that line to: `$("#train-submit").click(function(){addTrain(database)})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$("#train-submit").click({arg1: "something", arg2: "something else"}, addTrain);
```

And then in the function definition you can access like

```
function addTrain(event){
    event.data.arg1;
    event.data.arg2;
```

Comment: what is .data in this context?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: data is the object attached to the event that contains all the data you send with the event trigger